# Download files with ReactJS and NodeJS (Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I want to download a youtube video. The user enters the URL in a html input (Reactjs bases UI) and then a window opens to save the file to the desired destination.

React.js

```js
const handleOnSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        await handleApiCall(youTubeUrl);
    };

    const handleApiCall = async (url) => {
        const data = { url };
        try {
            const response = await fetch('/download', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            });
            console.log(response);

            return response;
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Node.js:

```js
app.post('/download',(req, res) => {
    const body = req.body;
    const { url } = body;

    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=video.mp3');

    ytdl(url, { format: 'mp3' }).pipe(res);

});
```

The header property should prompt the user for the download destination.
However, the headers are not sent when I double check on client side.

I am not able to identify the issue.

Comment: personally id respond from the POST request to /download with a token, HMAC of a secret and body.url, then clientside simply open a new tab with /download?url=...&token=... rehash for the check, this way you not got to mess about with createObjectURL, adheres to rest and can force download natively

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do you have a code example? It is hard for me to follow what you are saying. I am new to frontend development with ReactJS.